# Function is not working when called with AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have:

**call.php**:

```
function ajaxnotify(){
   notify('hello');
}
function notify($a){
echo "
    <script src=\"/js/jquery.min.js\"></script>
    <script src=\"//cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js\"></script>
    <script>
    $(function(){
        socket = io.connect(\"MY IP AND PORT\",{secure: true});
        socket.emit('say', {'msg': '$a'})
    });
    </script>
    ";
}
switch($_GET["do"]){
case "1":
     ajaxnotify();
     break;
case "2":
     notify();
     break;
}
```

and this code absolutely works when I directly go to mysite/call.php. But when I use:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "call.php?do=1",
            data: "",
            success: function(html){

            }
        });
```

It just doesn't work. it works when I'm directly going to page, but it doesn't work when I call ajax function from html.
Where is my mistake, guys?

Comment: When you're passing query string do then use type "GET" else pass in data: {do=1}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're sending the request using `POST`, yet using `$_GET` to retrieve the variable in PHP.

Change the `type: "POST"` in jQuery, to `type: 'GET'`. Here's a complete example:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'call.php',
  data: { do = 1 },
  success: function(html) {
    console.log(html); // to at least verify the response
  }
});
```

Comment: only for changing this he can not get result bez he write jquery code on request page just see .... we can't do this ..... for resolving this he should be call some other way or send request same page

Comment: m not taking about html , it's for jquery  see call.php he just don't aware about php and jquery

Comment: @NavnitMishra you're not right, my friend, I'm coding about 9 years

Comment: oky then try m not as long duration but m sure on the request page we can't run jquery .....

Comment: @NavnitMishra I've stripped other part of html for ease

Comment: Thank you for your help, Rory!